# Testing a stock market API using Python

Tags: python, stock, alpha-vantage

I'm testing out a stock market API, using alpha vantage. I've already got my API Key, and other parameters and followed the steps that have been given in the API documentation.

Here's my code:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.alphavantage.co.query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=TSLA&interval=1min&apikey=IJP9K6ENTHAVAUHF"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
print(data)
```

Now according go the docs, this should work. I've already entered the parameters such as the symbol for TSLA (Tesla), a time interval of 1 minute, and my own API key,
but for some reason this code just does not work.

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Armand S\Desktop\Python Files\D36 Stock Trading API.py", line 28, in <module> 
    response = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\Users\Armand S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Armand S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Armand S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 529, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Armand S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 645, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Armand S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 501, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You have a mistake on your URL. It's "/query" and not ".query". Also, you shouldn't share your API key online.